# Existe algum seletor jQuery que pegue o html de sua própria tag e também o conteúdo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Exemplo:

```
   <div id="quadro" style="float:left">
       <h1>Quadro de horários</h1>
   </div>
```

Se eu utilizar `$("#quadro").html()` eu só obtenho o h1, porém quero o html do h1 e da própria div.

Estou precisando de algo dinâmico, que independa de ter "parentes" ou filhos definidos.

Comment: primeiramente acredito que o correto seria assim $(".quadro").html(), pois você está tratando uma classe e um não um id

Comment: Beleza, foi so uma distração na hora de formular. Vou corrigir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery não tem essa função, mas é possível utilizar a propriedade [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), como é uma propriedade do objeto javascript (e não jQuery) é preciso pegar o elemento com [`.get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) ou como array (no exemplo) para pegar o primeiro elemento selecionado.

Dessa forma fica:

```
$(".quadro")[0].outerHTML
```

Ainda é possível fazer com javascript puro, utilizando [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector('.quadro').outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você utilizar

`$(".quadro")` nesse momento você tem todos os elementos que contém essa classe dentro do mesmo, e com isso você consegue navegar no elemento e nos seus childs.

se você utilizar o método .html(), você vai conter apensar o html dos seus childs(string), o que você realmente precisa, do elemento dentro do selector, ou do html em string ?